# Setting the 'charset' property on the Content-Type header in the golang HTTP FileServer

Tags: http, go, character-encoding

I've got an issue when testing a golang web app. In the deployed version, nginx fronts the application and explicitly sets `charset utf8;` so that all textual content types are appended with a charset declaration.

In testing, I'm hitting the golang application directly, and here the content type does not have a charset set. This is causing problems when trying to serve libraries like [d3](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/v3.5.6/d3.js#L1261) which has lines like:

```
var ε = 1e-6, ε2 = ε * ε, π = Math.PI, τ = 2 * π, τε = τ - ε, halfπ = π / 2, d3_radians = π / 180, d3_degrees = 180 / π;
```

Because golang doesn't specify the charset, these are rendered in chrome as:

```
var Îµ = 1e-6, Îµ2 = Îµ * Îµ....
```

What's the best way of getting the golang http server to output the charset=utf8 declaration on the HTTP headers?

Comment: I assume you mean the Go HTTP server, not Chrome? Just `w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")` (if that's the content type) in the relevant handlers, and/or in middleware to apply it to multiple handlers.

Comment: Erk, fixed the typo. I'm using the fileserver to serve a directory of different files and mimetypes, so setting it manually might not really work, unless I reimplement the existing content type sniffing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileServer calls [mime.TypeByExtension](http://godoc.org/mime#TypeByExtension) to get the content type. If no type is registered for the extension, then FileServer calls [http.DetectContentType](http://godoc.org/net/http#DetectContentType) to guess the type from the contents of the file.

If a text/ content type does not specify a charset parameter, then the mime package automatically adds the 'charset=utf-8' parameter to the content type.

To debug this problem, check to see if the system mime.types file specifies a content type for the file extension and that the charset parameter is'charset=utf-8' or the charset parameter is not set.

If the system mime.types entry is missing or incorrect, then call [mime.AddExtensionType](http://godoc.org/mime#AddExtensionType) to override the system setting. This can be called once before any content is served.

Comment: I tried to `mime.AddExtensionType(".js","application/javascript; charset=utf8")` as the first line in `main()` but it made no difference. Also, while I'm testing on OSX, doing the same test on linux resulted in the `js` file being just served as `application/javascript` without a charset parameter.

Comment: *edit* this program seems to still serve javascript as `application/javascript` on a mac: http://play.golang.org/p/AIWPjrOGOt

Comment: Ok, that's weird - it works for me now as well.  I think I was running into a chrome caching issue.