# http.FileServer response with wrong mime "Content-Type"

Tags: javascript, go, content-type, mime, fileserver

I'm using http.FileServer to serve a directory of mp3 files, which my template then `src` in javascript. The response, however, uses the `Content-Type` `text/html` instead of `audio/mpeg`. How do I set the mime type which the FileServer responds with, I saw this question [Setting the 'charset' property on the Content-Type header in the golang HTTP FileServer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32301463/setting-the-charset-property-on-the-content-type-header-in-the-golang-http-fil) , but I'm still not sure how to override the mime type.

My code looks like the following:

```
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir(dir))
http.Handle("/media", http.StripPrefix("/media", fs))
http.HandleFunc("/", p.playlistHandler)
http.ListenAndServe(":5177", nil)
```

and the error I get is:

```
HTTP "Content-Type" of "text/html" is not supported. Load of media resource http://localhost:5177/media/sample1.mp3 failed.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a problem of content types. Your `fs` handler isn't getting called when you request the mp3. You need to add a `/` to your pattern `/media` and the strip prefix like this

```
http.Handle("/media/", http.StripPrefix("/media/", fs))
```

The reason is in the documentation of [net/http.ServeMux](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux)

> Patterns name fixed, rooted paths, like "/favicon.ico", or rooted subtrees,
>   like "/images/" (note the trailing slash). Longer patterns take precedence
>   over shorter ones, so that if there are handlers registered for both
>   "/images/" and "/images/thumbnails/", the latter handler will be called for
>   paths beginning "/images/thumbnails/" and the former will receive requests
>   for any other paths in the "/images/" subtree.

With just `/media` you're registering a handler for a path but with a trailing slash it considers it a `rooted subtree` and will serve requests under that tree.

Comment: Hi, can you help me with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73462973/flutter-web-the-script-from-was-loaded-even-though-its-mime-type-text-plai