# How can I set correct http.FileServer mime types?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, go

Is there any way to overwrite the content-type used in FileServer?
I have simple REST server written in golang, and now i want add some "frontend" in Vue.

Html/js files are served from `/static/` folder and **almost** everything works fine...

Almost, except Vue files.

My `/static/` is served by:

```golang
fs := http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/"))
router.PathPrefix("/static/").Handler(http.StripPrefix("/static/", fs))
```

all `*.vue` files are served with `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`, and all browsers throws error:

```
Failed to load module script:
Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/plain". 
Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
```

How overwrite this Content-type? Maybe something like `Handler.extension_map` in python?

I tried:

```golang
log.Println(mime.TypeByExtension(".vue"))
mime.AddExtensionType(".vue", "application/javascript")
log.Println(mime.TypeByExtension(".vue"))
// Returns:
// 2022/01/14 11:45:50 
// 2022/01/14 11:45:50 application/javascript
```

Which works fine itself, but is apparently ignored by FileServer.

Alternatively, how else to solve this problem?

P.S. Yes, i saw:
[http.FileServer response with wrong mime "Content-Type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520045/http-fileserver-response-with-wrong-mime-content-type)
But didn't help in my case.

Comment: Normally, you would build `.vue` files into JavaScript, and serve the result. It's unusual to serve `.vue` files themselves, and `application/javascript` isn't really the correct MIME because it contains more than just JavaScript.

Comment: Use `mime.AddExtensionType(".vue", "application/javascript")`. The function mime.TypeByExtension is not ignored by FileServer.  https://go.dev/play/p/cVTvVS1NgEJ

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks a lot. I don't know why, but putting AddExtensionType directly before FileServer works "better". Previously was in the main function at beginning of code.